# MySql Timetable query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database table which is inputted from raw data.  It has a list of trains which is formatted as such:

```
RI   TrainNo   TripNo   Location   ArrTime   DepTime
TS:  171       1        HMS                  17280
TE:  171       8        UPM        45360    
TS:  171       9        UPM                  53640
TE:  171       16       HMS        87120
```

TS is the point the train starts its journey, and TE is the point the train ends.

I want to establish if a train is running at a given time, so ran the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.TrainNo
              , s1.StartTime
              , s1.StartTrip
              , s1.StartLocation
              , s2.StowTime
              , s2.StowTrip
              , s2.StowLocation 
           FROM `tt.data` tt 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT TrainNo
                     , DepTime as StartTime
                     , TripNo as StartTrip
                     , Location as StartLocation 
                  FROM `tt.data` 
                 WHERE RI = 'TS:' 
              ) s1 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT TrainNo
                     , ArrTime StowTime
                     , TripNo StowTrip
                     , Location StowLocation 
                  FROM `tt.data` 
                 WHERE RI = 'TE:' 
              ) s2 
             ON s1.TrainNo = tt.TrainNo 
            AND s1.TrainNo = s2.TrainNo 
            AND s1.StartTime < s2.StowTime
            AND 45350 > s1.StartTime 
            AND 45350 < s2.StowTime 
            AND tt.TrainNo = 171
```

The output:

```
TrainNo StartTime StartTrip StartLocation StowTime StowTrip StowLocation
171     17280     1         HMS           45360    8        UPM
171     17280     1         HMS           87120    16       HMS
```

The first row is correct, and the train is running between Trips 1 and 8.  However the second row is incorrect, if the time was greater than 45360 then it would tell me the train is running when in fact it doesn't run again until 53640.

What would be a good way of removing this line?

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result then: just the first record?

Comment: `tt.data` seems like a poor name for a table. It's generally a terrible idea to include punctuation in table names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solve this is to properly self-join the start and end of each trip. One way to do it is, for a given train start, to search for the closest end trip of the same train. You could do this with a correlated subquery, like so:

```
select 
    t1.trainno,
    t1.deptime  starttime,
    t1.tripno     starttrip,
    t1.location startlocation,
    t2.arrtime  stowtime,
    t2.tripno     stowtrip,
    t2.location stowlocation
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 
    on  t2.trainno = t1.trainno
    and t2.ri = 'TE:'
    and t2.arrtime = (select min(t3.arrtime) from mytable t3 where t3.arrtime > t1.deptime)
where 
    t1.ri = 'TS:'
    and t1.trainno = 171
    and t1.deptime < 45350
    and t2.arrtime > 45350
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9f9383b90c1bb772d5193e539c076316)**:

```
trainno | starttime | starttrip | startlocation | stowtime | stowtrip | stowlocation
------: | --------: | --------: | :------------ | -------: | -------: | :-----------
    171 |     17280 |         1 | HMS           |    45360 |        8 | UPM
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, this looks promising however the line ```(select min(t3.arrtime) from mytable t3 where t3.arrtime > t1.deptime)``` makes my data return no results for some reason

Comment: @AndyCutting: well this does work for the sample data you provided, as you can see in the db fiddle I linked in my answer... Maybe this data is not representative of your real dataset? If so, you would need to ask a new question, with proper sample data...

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(TripNo   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,RI CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,TrainNo INT NOT NULL 
,Location CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,ArrTime INT NULL
,DepTime INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,'TS',171,'HMS',NULL,17280),
( 8,'TE',171,'UPM',45360,NULL),
( 9,'TS',171,'UPM',NULL,53640),
(16,'TE',171,'HMS',87120,NULL);

SELECT a.*
     , b.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
            , MIN(y.tripno) y_trip 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.tripno > x.tripno 
          AND y.trainno = x.trainno 
          AND y.ri = 'te' 
        WHERE x.ri = 'ts' 
        GROUP 
           BY x.tripno
     ) a
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.tripno = a.y_trip
 WHERE 45350 BETWEEN a.deptime AND b.arrtime;

+--------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+
| TripNo | RI | TrainNo | Location | ArrTime | DepTime | y_trip | TripNo | RI | TrainNo | Location | ArrTime | DepTime |
+--------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+
|      1 | TS |     171 | HMS      |    NULL |   17280 |      8 |      8 | TE |     171 | UPM      |   45360 |    NULL |
+--------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* window functions do what you want:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             lead(arrtime) over (partition by trainno order by tripno) as next_arrtime
      from tt.data d
     ) d
where ri = 'TS:' and
      45350 > deptime and
      45350 < next_arrtime
```